# How to validate input field against the database in Yii 2.0?

Tags: php, database, validation, yii

Suppose I have a field name id and I want the user to enter some integer in the id field but at the same   time I want to check that id against the database whether it exists or not. If it exists then it should show some error.

Is there a function to achieve this in Yii 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is from a model, you can have a `unique` rule to it in the validation rules.

In your model, you have a `rules()` function:

```
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('name', 'required'),
        array('some_id', 'unique'),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. It works! Is there a way that I can do this on the client side before form submit?

Comment: Yeah, [here](http://www.phpcmsframework.com/2014/07/steps-to-use-ajax-form-validation-in-yii.html) is one example how to do it, of course you can implement the logic yourself if it fits your needs better. But basic AJAX validation is pretty much integrated into Yii, you just have to tell it what to do where.